# Plotting categorical variables using a bar diagram/bar chart

Tags: stata

[data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tK8hT.png)

I am trying to plot a bar graph for both sept and oct waves. As in the image you can see the id are the individuals who are surveyed across time. So on the one graph I need to plot sept in-house, oct in-house,  sept out-house, oct out-house and just have to show the proportion of people who said yes in sept in-house, oct in-house, sept out-house, oct out-house. Not all the categories have to be taken into account.

Also I have to show whiskers for 95% confidence intervals for each of the respective categories.

Comment: What have you tried so far? `help graph bar` is good a place to start.

Comment: This is an entire small project with data presented clearly but awkwardly and zero attempt at code. I concur with a previous down-voter that it is a poor question. Please present data example as code and show some attempt at code. SO isn't a code-writing service.

Comment: The Stata tag wiki gives lengthy advice on posting a good question.

Answer (score 0):

```
* Example generated by -dataex-. For more info, type help dataex
clear
input float(id sept_outhouse sept_inhouse oct_outhouse oct_inhouse)
 1 1 1 1 1
 2 2 2 2 2
 3 3 3 3 3
 4 4 3 3 3
 5 4 4 3 3
 6 4 4 3 3
 7 4 4 4 1
 8 1 1 1 1
 9 1 1 1 1
10 1 1 1 1
end
label values sept_outhouse codes
label values sept_inhouse codes
label values oct_outhouse codes
label values oct_inhouse codes
label def codes 1 "yes", modify
label def codes 2 "no", modify
label def codes 3 "don't know", modify
label def codes 4 "refused", modify

save tokenexample, replace 

rename (*house) (house*)
reshape long house, i(id) j(which) string 
replace which = subinstr(proper(which), "_", " ", .)
gen yes = house == 1
label def WHICH 1 "Sept Out" 2 "Sept In" 3 "Oct Out" 4 "Oct In"
encode which, gen(WHICH) label(WHICH)
statsby, by(WHICH) clear: ci proportion yes, jeffreys 

set scheme s1color 
twoway scatter mean WHICH ///
|| rspike ub lb WHICH, xla(1/4, noticks valuelabel) xsc(r(0.9 4.1)) ///
xtitle("") legend(off) subtitle(Proportion Yes with 95% confidence interval)
```

This has to be solved backwards.

1. The means and confidence intervals have to be plotted using `twoway` as `graph bar` is a dead-end here, because it does not allow whiskers too.
2. The confidence limits have to be put in variables before the graphics. Some graph commands, notably `graph bar`, will calculate means for you, but as said that is a dead end. So, we need to calculate the means too.
3. To do that you need an indicator variable for Yes.
4. The best way I know to get the results then is to `reshape` to a different structure and then apply `ci proportion` under `statsby`.

As a detail, the option `jeffreys` is explicit as a signal that there are different methods for the confidence interval calculation. You should choose one knowingly.

[image]